# Bug in django voting?

Tags: python, django, django-voting

I am trying to retrieve the top voted items in Django. Here's the relevant line of code:

```
originalList = [x[0] for x in list(Vote.objects.get_top(Item, endIdx))[startIdx:]]
```

The indexes are for pagination purposes. When I try to load the page in a browser, I get:

```
AttributeError at /items/top/
'Settings' object has no attribute 'DATABASE_ENGINE'
```

However, the attribute it should be looking for is not DATABASE_ENGINE, rather, it is in `DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']`. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Yea, it looks like that code hasn't been touched in [4 years](https://code.google.com/p/django-voting/source/list). It claims

```
Note that this application requires Python 2.3 or later, and Django
0.97-pre or later. You can obtain Python from http://www.python.org/ and
Django from http://www.djangoproject.com/.
```

At the time, that was most likely the way to define a database engine and is now deprecated. Personally, I would avoid using this, there are probably other issues with it as well...

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following which I guess is the simplest thing to do until django voting is fixed upstream:

at the end of your `settings.py`, append:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a pre-django1.0 app, you should check the branches on github: https://github.com/brosner/django-voting/network and use an active fork or consider using an alternative app for this.